# Codeigniter - after submit form getting 404 error

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to Codeigniter and I am trying learn it by building simple admin panel.. but in the last days I got stuck on some error:

When I send/submit the login information I get 404 error. here is my controller code:

class Login extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index()
{   
    if($this->aauth->is_loggedin()){redirect('/dashboard');}

    $this->sign_in();

}

public function sign_in()
{   
    $this->load->view('header');    
    $this->load->view('login'); 
    $this->load->view('footer');
}   

public function validate()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|valid_email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean');


    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
        //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
        $this->load->view('header');    
        $this->load->view('login'); 
        $this->load->view('footer');

    }else{
        //Check for database and redirect to private area
        redirect('/dashboard');
    }   

}
```

}

I've also shared my whole project on github, because its may related to some other file:

https://github.com/shaimoryosef/admin

Please try to help me find what is the problem..

Thanks
Shai

Comment: share your view part as well, what action you are passing in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two thing you need to change

first : in view/login.php

Login is link

```
`<a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>`
```

change to button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</button>
```

And second put index.php in `form_open()`

`<?php echo form_open('index.php/login/validate'); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

This link

```
 <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">Login</a>
```

is wrong, that's why you are probably getting the 404 error, due to the href attribute which points to index.html.

If you want to submit the form just put a submit button and you will get to login/validate through the form action. My advice is to either use

```
<?php echo form_submit('mysubmit', 'Submit'); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo echo form_button(array( 'type' => 'submit',  'content' => 'Login')); ?>
```

functions from form helper. Check the CI [user guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) and pick whichever suits you best.

Comment: One more thing. Chances are that you will probably get another error because of redirect('/dashboard'); Use redirect('dashboard'); instead, remove slash is not needed.